# How to replace HTML Contents?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am new to C# programming. As a study I am making an  application that will send an email to employees whose birthday falls on a day.
I am able to achieve the task of sending email. however my email is html enabled where I want to display the name of Birthday employee.
On HTML page, I have created a table where there will be a row for name.

```
<tr>
<td> Name</td>
<td>#Name#</td>
</tr>
```

Records I am extracting from database and storing them in data adapter and then in a string.
I am using `String Replace()` function to update the name.

```
DataTable dt = null;
string Body = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path of HTML file");
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("query"))
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", DateTime.Today.Day);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", DateTime.Today.Month);
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
}
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string name = row["Name"].ToString();
    string dob = row["DOB"].ToString();

    DateTime dob1 = DateTime.Parse(row["DOB"].ToString());
    if ((dob1.Day == DateTime.Today.Day) && (dob1.Month == DateTime.Today.Month))
    {
        Body = Body.Replace("#Name#", name);
        Body = Body.Replace("#dob#", dob);

        using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("From Email address", "To email address"))
        {
            mm.Subject = "Birthday Greetings";
            mm.Body = Body;
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "Mail Server";
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = credentials;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mm);
        }
    }
}
```

Replace function is being executed under a foreach loop to check for all the employees.
However, if more than one employee birthday falls together I  get same name in all emails. I guess replace function works for first time and doesn't replace in the next iteration.

Request if some efficient method be provided.

Comment: i would recommend HTMLAgilityPack https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/

Comment: You need to show us more code where you replace for more than one employee. Replace function replaces all instances of the string.

Comment: Do you need to send email to individual OR single email with all birthday employee name ?

Comment: Are you joining tables in that query?

Comment: @Sunil I have edited the post. Code is available

Comment: @GaurangDave Individual email containing single name and other details will be sent to a mailing group.

Comment: @Immersive No, query is extracting data from a single table.

Comment: Then what is the issue? You can replace the legends in your html file and send it. I am using the same approach for generating notification email and till now no issue. For safe side I use "##NAME##"  double # and UPPERCASE for legends

Comment: @GaurangDave Suppose two empoyees abc and xyz have birthday on same date. Then 02 mails are sent but both mails show abc as name and xyz name is not updated in second mail.

Comment: @Kartikeya Read HTML template file from location in your loop each time. What you need it html text with #NAME# etc. I think you are reading it one time and them running loop. In each Row you access in loop, use fresh HTML template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read HTML template file from location in your loop each time. What you need is html text with #NAME# etc. I think you are reading it one time and them running loop. In each Row you access in loop, use fresh HTML template.

Comment: Yes, it worked now. I am initialising the body now from inside the loop and now mails with correct names are being sent. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @Kartikeya Cheers buddy. Please mark as an answer / upvote if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

First loop your string has `#Name`.

Second loop, now the string that is stored in `Body` doesn't have `#Name` anymore, so it doesn't get updated any more.

You need to reinitialized the `Body` variable from the template in the loop.

Comment: First loop and second loop words are bit confusing, I suggest  that you should use word "iteration". :)

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct I think it is because on the first execution of your loop. The whole body string is being replaced and being assign to the body variable hence your "#Name#" and "#dob#" cannot be found on the next execution. You can read the body string every loop so you have the original string each iteration to replace with.